How can you automate security audits of javascript packages when using Rails importmap?
When using a package manager like npm you have the ability to run npm audit on your package.json file to check for any known vulnerabilities. You can then add this check to your CI Pipeline to continually check for issues.
However, if you use Rails 7 importmaps, you're often referencing CDNs or packages that are downloaded to the vendor folder so what strategies are people using to automatically check JavaScript packages for known vulnerabilities in this situation?

From importmap-rails documentation "Checking for outdated or vulnerable packages": ./bin/importmap audit - checks the NPM registry for known security issues.

Perfect - thank you.

As pointed by @engineersmnky, you can audit dependencis for knonw issues using ./bin/importmap audit or using a third-paryy librarty like bundler-audit
